# Implement range in Go

Tags: go

I have a `type List []string` and I am implementing some standard functions like `Insert`, `DeleteAt` etc. I would like to implement `range` so I can iterate the list easily.
I cannot seem to find the way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason to re-implement range since the range keyword will work on type List.

```
var l List
for i, v := range l {
    /* whatever */
}
```

Comment: omg.. i had a `var l *List` and did `range l` instead of `range *l`.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in Go to implement range yourself for a given type. Range only works for Go's built-in data structures: slices, maps and channels (and arrays?).

Comment: Range also works on strings to iterate over UTF-8 runes. (And yes, should work on arrays too, but one rarely uses arrays directly in Go.)